# How do I get continuation token when querying Azure Table Storage via REST API on PowerShell?

Tags: rest, azure-table-storage, powershell-core

I am using PWSH 7 / REST API to query a table with more than 1000 entries, and I can query it fine using this code:

```
$RGName = "MyResourceGroup"
$StorageAccount = "MyStorageAccount"
$TableName = "MyTable"
$SA = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $StorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RGName -verbose
$Accesskey = ($SA | Get-AzStorageAccountKey).value[0]

$Version = "2021-08-06"
$Table_url = "https://$StorageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$TableName"
$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$stringToSign = "$GMTTime`n/$StorageAccount/$TableName"
$HMACSHA = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$HMACSHA.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Accesskey)
$Signature = $HMACSHA.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
$Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Signature)
$Headers = @{
    'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime
    Authorization  = "SharedKeyLite " + $StorageAccount + ":" + $Signature
    "x-ms-version" = $Version
    Accept         = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata"
}
$Item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Table_url -Headers $Headers -ContentType application/json
```

However, I don't get a continuation token returned, so I don't see a way to get the next entries in the table.
According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Entities), it looks like I should be getting one.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Entities), the continuation tokens (`x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey` and `x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey`) are returned in response headers.

To get response headers in `Invoke-RestMethod` Cmdlet, you would need to specify [`-ResponseHeadersVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#-responseheadersvariable) variable and then you should be able to get those response headers.

Comment: Thanks.
Just to add to that answer, I was trying to add in a variable using -ResponseHeadersVariable as not giving it input gave me an error. This answer made me try without the $ which then created a variable, i.e. `-ResponseHeadersVariable response` created a variable called $response.